# Am I using websockets correctly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket, pusher

**Background:**

- I am using the API from Pusher.
- I am using PHP serverside.
- I have installed the Pusher package server side via composer.

**How I am using it**

I am building a slide-show that is controlled by a single user. If I want that one person to change the slide for all the people on that page then I make an AJAX call with the number slide that the user moved to.

```
$('#nextCard').click(function(){
    if ($('#card-' + (cardId + 1)).length != 0) {  // if there is a next card
        $('#card-' + (cardId)).hide();             // hide current card
        cardId++;                                  // increment the card id
        $('#card-' + (cardId)).show();             // and show the next card
        location.hash = cardId;

        /**
         * make ajax call to push function
         */
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('learn/pusher'); ?>',
            data: {card_id: cardId},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
        });
    }
});
```

This number is sent via ajax to the server where it is channelled via pusher.

Pusher then sends the slide number real time to all users on the same page... in effect *pushing* changes to different peoples screens.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications');
channel.bind('new-notification', function(data) {

    // call something here

});
```

Then the changes are effected by the function that is called when the data is pushed.

**My question**

I was under the impression that Websockets was an alternative/replacement to AJAX and other similar technologies...but here I find myself relying on AJAX to send my Websockets data to pusher from the server side.

I thought that Websockets was advantageous over AJAX because it was faster, but here I find myself being bottlenecked by AJAX.

**So am I using websockets correctly here?**

Comment: why wouldn't you use pusher to emit the update instead of ajax?

Comment: If you already have a webSocket connection to the server, then you can send data to the server either via the webSocket connection or via Ajax (your choice).

Comment: "*Websockets was an alternative/replacement to AJAX*" Not exactly, it has the main advantage to be bidirectionnal, so server can send message to client. That means that a websocket connection can replace repeatively AJAX requests to server to get latest state. Personally I still use AJAX requests, even if I have an opened websocket connection, to send "one-shot" queries to my HTTP API.

Comment: Interesting, I find ajax easier for "one-shot" events too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AJAX to send requests to your server which in turn triggers a Pusher event in order to broadcast it to subscribers is an idiomatic way of using Pusher. The underlying WebSockets technology is bidirectional (more info [here](https://pusher.com/websockets)), but Pusher's pub/sub model is unidirectional.

One alternative for your use-case is to use [client events](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#trigger-events). This allows you to trigger events directly from the client. The extra consideration with doing this is you have to use private or presence channels.

Comment: Absolutely nailed it!